# Selecting certain dataframe columns with string processing

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, dataframe

I'm trying to select a set of columns from a dataset that meets a certain condition. So for example I have these columns in the dataframe:

```
['string_category_4', 'string_category_24', 'range_category_6',
  'range_category_17', 'int_numeric_21', 'string_category_15',
  'float_numeric_8', 'int_bool_19', 'int_bool_2']
```

Each of the trailing numbers in the column name is going to be a unique identifier, regardless of the prefix like `category` or `numeric`. I would like to select all the columns which are `<=10` so it should return a list for me that is:

```
['string_category_4', 'range_category_6', 'float_numeric_8',
 'int_bool_2']
```

Is there a way with either string processing or even simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
columns = [
    'category_4', 'category_24', 'category_6',
    'category_17', 'numeric_21', 'category_15',
    'numeric_8', 'bool_19', 'bool_2'
]
filtered_columns = [col for col in columns if int(col.rsplit('_')[-1]) <= 10]
print(filtered_columns)
```

**Output:**

```
> ['category_4', 'category_6', 'numeric_8', 'bool_2']
```

Comment: This logic is sound, but how would you handle columns with names such as `string_category_11` for example which have two underscores?

Comment: That's what the `[-1]` is for (selecting the last item). Split the string, then select the last item only. BTW, you could use `.split("_")` as well. Even better is `.rsplit(''_", 1)`. `"string_category_11".rsplit("_")` yields `["string", "category", "11"]`. By using `[-1]`, you are selecting the last item in that list.